# Is asking for an analogy on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

To quote [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681101/13476485):

> An analogy usually helps.

I'm currently learning `Generators` and `yield` in Python, and writing code to better understand the topic. I also find having an analogy does help make it easier. Consider this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54359/how-would-you-explain-multi-threading-to-a-seven-year-old-kid) from SESE, most of the answers are analogies and the accepted answer contains a comment to turn it into an analogy.

While the person answering may use an analogy, is asking for it appropriate?

Comment: I doubt that will be on-topic on SO main. But I don't have a good analogy to explain why I think that is so ...

Comment: As an educator, I think a place for such questions could be useful.

Comment: That seems like a perfect example of an opinion-based question. How can you judge if any particular answer is "correct"? Worth noting that the question you linked is locked for being off-topic even on SESE.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery It may be on topic on [CSE.SE](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) though

Comment: You don't ask for an analogy. Instead, you ask for an explanation of how something works. If the answerers want to provide analogies, that's fine.